# How to SSH to a docker-machine created by quickstart terminal?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-quickstart-terminal

Whenever I run the **Docker Quickstart Terminal** a virtual machine gets commissioned. It is of a linux machine with an IP address.

Is it possible to connect to that docker-machine via SSH? If so, what is the default password of root? and is there a need for a .pem/.ppk key?

Comment: Does `docker-machine ssh` work?  I don't remember what credentials it uses but I think pretty much the only user in the VM is root.

Comment: Yeap I figured it out after posting this question. `docker-machine ssh <machine-name>` works